# how to work with classes

Tags: c++, class

I have been learning on classes in c++ and I got a certain code from an old russian book its about a book class, I tried modifying it and running it its not working may some help me understanding why the authour used this code(what does strdup do?)

`Author = strdup(autho);`

inside the constructor and was wrong with this line of code

```
Book s("edgar", "science", "chemistry for dummies", "502","12.11.13","1.12.96");
```

Anyone with a simple straight explanation?

Main code below

```
using namespace std;

class Book{

    char * Author;
    char * Type;
    char * Title;
    int * Pages;
    unsigned int * Yearpublished;
    unsigned int  * Publishing;

    Book(char * autho, char * type, char * title,   int * pages, unsigned int * yearpublished, unsigned int  * publishing ){

        Author = strdup(autho);
        Type = strdup(type);
        Title = strdup(title);
        Pages = pages;
        Yearpublished = yearpublished;
        Publishing = publishing;

    }

    ~Book(){

        if(Author != NULL){

             free(Author);

        }
        if(Type != NULL){

            free(Type);
        }

        if(Title != NULL){

            free(Title);
        }
    }

};

int main(){

    cout << "main start" << endl;

    Book s("edgar", "science", "chemistry for dummies", "502","12.11.13","1.12.96");

    cout << "main finish" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you are writing is not C++. Please throw out all of the `char*` lines and replace them with `std::string`.

Comment: Assuming you've copied the code out of the book correctly, the best advice I can give you is to stop using that book. This code is *unforgivably* broken. There is no point in the history of C++ at which this code would have compiled and worked as expected. I cannot think of a worse example snippet of C++ code.

Comment: `const char*` is an acceptable data type for accessing strings, particularly when using string literals defined at compile time (eg `const char* menutitle = "File";`.  I personally avoid the string class unless I need the extra functionality like `s1="s1:"+s2;`, and even then I usually end up using `s1.c_str();` when passing them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many, many things wrong with the code posted. So many things that virtually every single line is in error.

One of the most obvious is that you're trying to store a year as an `int *`, and then passing in a *string* containing `"12.11.13"`. That  doesn't work. You're doing the same for `pages`; accepting an `int*` and passing in a string *containing* an int. You can't do that, that isn't how pointers work. Most of your usage of pointers indicates that you don't really know what the `*` does, and you should stop and read about pointers before you introduce some *very* difficult to track down bugs into your code. You should either store your year as a string (very bad idea) or store it as an integer in [unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which is pretty standard.

You should remove `using namespace std` and replace it with `#include <string>`. You should throw out all the lines that start with `char*`, and replace them with `std::string` and throw out your `int*` lines and make them `int`.

You're also declaring a private constructor and destructor. You need to add `public:` after the member variable declarations but before `Book()`. Then you should throw out the body of your constructor and use initializer lists.

You're also not including `<iostream>`, so your `cout` calls are probably causing errors.

Once you've done the above, you should remove the destructor `~Book()` completely.

For example:

```
class Book{

    std::string Author;
    // ...
    int Pages;
    // ...

    public:

    Book(std::string author, /* ... */ int pages /* ... */)
    : Author(author), Pages(pages) {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many errors there.

1) You are using way too many pointers. You do not need even a single pointer in this snippet of code. As pointed by meagar, you can replace `char*` by `std::string`. You do not need pointer to integers or unsigned integers, you can use the type as-is.

2) You are passing strings of characters (denoted by the use of quotes "") instead of numbers when calling the constructor. If you want to pass numbers, do not use quotes.

3) You are using "using namespace std" which is wrong for many reasons and has been explained so many times on so many websites that I will let you search why.

4) You are using `free()` on memory that you have not allocated with `malloc()` (and that would not even be suggested in C++ since we have `new` and `delete`).

Edit: If this is truly code you have taken from a book on C++, then please use this book as fire starter because it's not worth more than that.

Here is a *much* simpler version of your code that is written in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Book
{
private:
    std::string Author, Type, Title, Publishing;
    unsigned int Pages, Yearpublished;

public:
    Book(const char* autho, const char* type, const char* title, unsigned int pages,
        unsigned int yearpublished, std::string publishing )
    {
        Author = strdup(autho);
        Type = strdup(type);
        Title = strdup(title);
        Pages = pages;
        Yearpublished = yearpublished;
        Publishing = publishing;
    }

    ~Book()
    {

    }

};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "main start" << std::endl;
    Book s("edgar", "science", "chemistry for dummies", 502, 2012,"1.12.96");
    std::cout << "main finish" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

There is still much to improve but this will at least compile and run just fine.

Comment: +1 for recommending the book be used as kindling. Someone (who describes himself as "grumpy") deleted my answer, which said to discard the book and start over.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused of your question but i think you mainly ask for what is `strdup`:

It copies passed string and returns a pointer to jsut newly created one.
And in destructor you destroy these allocated strings, if any.